# Rolling restart Ignite full memory mode on K8s without losing data

Tags: ignite

I am running ignite on the k8s cluster with 5 pods and set backups = 1 https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/primary-and-backup-copies. Is there any way to do a rolling restart without losing data and how to check if the data is synced to other instances before restarting one after another

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor cache rebalancing process by using jmx
https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring-metrics/metrics#monitoring-rebalancing